# How to replace Assert.Fail() with FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assertions, fluent-assertions

We are currently converting some code that was using `Assert.IsTrue()`, `Assert.AreEqual()`, `Assert.IsNotNull()`, etc. The basic unit test assert Library for C#

We want to use FluentAssertions, like `value.Should().BeNull().`

I'm stuck on a few tests using `Assert.Fail()` in some locations. What should I use to efficiently replace those, since we want to do away with every single "Assert.*", and I can't find an equivalent in FluentAssertions?

Here is an example

```
[TestMethod, TestCategory("ImportantTest")]
public void MethodToTest_Circumstances_ExpectedResult()
{
    // Arrange
    var variable1 = new Type1() { Value = "hello" };
    var variable2 = new Type2() { Name = "Bob" };

    // Act
    try
    {
        MethodToTest(variable1, variable2);
        // This method should have thrown an exception
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Should().BeOfType<DataException>();
        ex.Message.Should().Be(Constants.DataMessageForMethod);
    }

    // Assert
    // test that variable1 was changed by the method
    variable1.Should().NotBeNull();
    variable1.Value.Should().Be("Hello!");
    // test that variable2 is unchanged because the method threw an exception before changing it
    variable2.Should().NotBeNull();
    variable2.Name.Should().Be("Bob");
}
```

Comment: Please post code samples of what you're stuck on.  Unit testing is an art.  We can't answer "What should I use to efficiently replace those..." without seeing what "those" are.

Comment: Usually an `Assert.Fail` is used in a code path that was reached because of a problem like `if(value == null) { Assert.Fail("should not be null");}` so how you convert them is completely based on the circumstances that lead the code to reach them.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `Assert.Throws` to start with, instead of the `try/Assert.Fail/catch` approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Restructure the test to utilize the `.ShouldThrow<>` assertion extension.

```
[TestMethod, TestCategory("ImportantTest")]
public void MethodToTest_Circumstances_ExpectedResult() {
    // Arrange
    var variable1 = new Type1() { Value = "hello" };
    var variable2 = new Type2() { Name = "Bob" };

    // Act
    Action act = () => MethodToTest(variable1, variable2);       

    // Assert
    // This method should have thrown an exception
    act.ShouldThrow<DataException>()
       .WithMessage(Constants.DataMessageForMethod);
    // test that variable1 was changed by the method
    variable1.Should().NotBeNull();
    variable1.Value.Should().Be("Hello!");
    // test that variable2 is unchanged because the method threw an exception before changing it
    variable2.Should().NotBeNull();
    variable2.Name.Should().Be("Bob");
}
```

In the above example, if the expected exception is not thrown the the assertion would fail, stopping the test case.

You should review the [documentation on asserting exceptions](https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/) to get a better understanding of how to use the library.

Answer (score 3):

Following the example in here, he just dealt away with the Assert.Fail -- and use action and .ShouldThrow
http://www.continuousimprover.com/2011/07/why-i-created-fluent-assertions-in.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this is equivalent:

throw new AssertionFailedException("Reason...");

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, in your specific example you should probably use `ShouldThrow<>()`.

However, in general, if no other FluentAssertions method applies, you can use:

```
Execute.Assertion.FailWith("[explain why this line should not be reached]");
```